# Effective methods of preventing people ripping HTML/CSS/JS off my site via right click “save-as”?

Tags: html, drm, css

PS: My last question was marked duplicated incorrectly. For all those marking this as a duplicate of the image copying question posted earlier, I am not interested in preventing just image copying. I am looking for methods for **all my html, css and js**, not just images

First of all, I understand that there is **NO** foolproof way to prevent others from ripping my site. (See: [Prevent my site from being copied](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38460/prevent-my-site-from-being-copied?newreg=43a9023080664712802c2c566f0eb819))

This question is not intended for that; rather, I am asking about methodologies to make website ripping more *difficult*.

Most of the ripping is done via "save-as" (through right clicking). Some of them are using cURL and wget.

1. I am aware that I can load html elements via dynamically generated ajax. This makes "save-as" saving an empty page.
2. I understand that there are javascript obfuscators out there which can obfuscate javascript. However, I don't think there are such tools out there for html and css.

Note: A significant portion of my website is dedicated to mobile users. So this makes flash out of the question.

What other methods should I look into?

Comment: Are your users asked for credentials?

Comment: Whomsoever is downvoting the question, please at least give a reason to go with it. This question has already created frustration for the person once, avoid doing it again and again.

Comment: @Limit If you hover your mouse over the down-arrow, a balloon with the reason will appear on your screen. There is no need to add another explanations.

Comment: @techraf I know about the tooltip option but clearly the OP is not satisfied with that logic so maybe someobody could just explain it once to him :) That's all

Comment: @Limit And other users are clearly not satisfied with the way OP handles this question, so I thought maybe I could just explain it to you. :) That's all.

Comment: All right! I'll let it go!

Comment: Compressing the code using tools which get rid of whitespace can make it such a mess to other developers that they are much less likely to use it. This doesn't prevent them from taking it but it does make it much harder for them to work with your code and it reduces your file size making your site load faster. I'm sure there are better tools for this but the following link is one Google came up with http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php

Answer (score 1):

The very nature of the Internet/web means that browsers must have something to parse in order to have something to display.  Thus, if you want users to have a site to display in their browsers, then it must be transmitted to their system where it then becomes vulnerable to scraping.  So your options are very limited.

You might consider a terminal-based system wherein the users are redirected to a terminal viewer.  The browser is actually on the terminal server.  Their clicks are transmitted to the server where the web browser renders the page.  The end users are effectively receiving a video stream of the website.   https://www.citrix.com/products/xenmobile/

Alternatively, you could consider writing an app that takes the place of the browser.  Write your webapp/website as a mobile app instead and distribute it through the app store.