# How to provide to your Webpage a security like Wix and how to break that security

Tags: web-application, drm

I have read several articles related to the "impossibility to fully protect your Website from being copied (please, check, for instance: [Prevent my site from being copied](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38460/prevent-my-site-from-being-copied)).

So, how is it possible for sites like Wix to avoid you getting an editable version of the Webpage you have created in their Website, even using tools like Httrak?

Or, if I am wrong, could you please advise how to full edit a Webpage created in Wix (of course, after downloading it, in your local machine)?

Comment: Wix is [so secure](https://www.contrastsecurity.com/security-influencers/dom-xss-in-wix.com), LOL

Answer (score 1):

Make sure httrak is setup to spoof a real browser (user agent), and try and slow the requests down. Wix probably blocks known download user agents.

See this page: 
https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html
You will need to search on the page as it's very long.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that the second part of your answer has not yet been responded.

You might find this article useful to get HTML, CSS and similar components from WIX to a new site without the WIX's protection. Hope this help!

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-convert-wix-to-wordpress-a-complete-guide-to-all-your-options